# Найти предложение с антонимами

Tags: егэ, антонимы

Т.к. точную формулировку задания не помню, приблизительно:

Укажите предложение с антонимами(ни каких уточнений вроде "контекстные" и п. не было)

1)7 2)x 3)x 4)27

...
(7)В глухой, далёкой деревне, где до ближайшей станции больше ста километров, где любая поездка становится целым путешествием, сама эта мысль казалась безумием.

...
(27)Таковы законы жизни: всё,что взлетело вверх, рано или поздно возвращается на землю.

Ну тут очевидно, но разве "далёкой" и "ближайшей" не они? Подозреваю, что замес в разной форме этих прилагательных..

Comment: Я ответил 1, меня смутила превосходная степень прилагательного "ближайшей" в отличии от обычного прилагательного "далёкой". Не знаю: могут ли прилагательные от этого перестать быть антонимами?

Comment: Если пришлют отчёты, в которых отмечены верные/неверные ответы, отпишусь<br>Если кому интересно, текст легко нашёлся в Сети, да ещё и с расставленными номерами предложений, это нормально<script>Alert('HuhHuhHuh!')</script>

Comment: Ой, ошибка, я ответил 4 именно потому что в 1ом варианте смутила превосходная степень, и на рано или поздно я как раз сразу обратил внимание

Answer (score 2):

(27)Таковы законы жизни: всё,что взлетело вверх, рано или поздно возвращается на землю.
Взлетело-возвращается.-контекстные антонимы.

Далёкая-ближайшая - правильно, антонимы

Comment: Тут, вроде, больше про пару *далёкой-ближайшей* спрашивают.

Comment: Да, это антонимы. А в 27 - контекстные антонимы.

Comment: тогда действительно, задание, для тестовой проверки довольно неоднозначное.

Comment: Но Дмитрий правильно разобрался, что речь не о контекстных, это я поспешила, вопрос прочитала невнимательно. А он молодец, значит, правильно ответил.

Comment: Увы, я не так ответил, см. выше

Answer (score 2):

а рано и поздно - забыли? Устойчивое сочетание, да, но построенное именно на антонимии

Comment: Конечно. Вот что значит зацикливаться на чём-то одном.

Answer (score 1):

взлетело вверх -возвращается на землю