# Когда стоит, а когда не стоит отвечать на школьные вопросы?

Tags: общие-вопросы

На наш форум частенько заглядывают школьники с тем, чтобы мы за них делали домашние задания, в то время как они сами не способны написать собственное имя без десяти ошибок. Обычно я такие вопросы закрываю сразу, но, когда вижу, что на них уже даны ответы, уже не трогаю — какой смысл?
Давайте как-то определимся: в какой ситуации мы отвечаем на школьные вопросы (когда идет откровенное школьное задание), а когда нет? А то сейчас надвигаются ЕГЭ и таких вопросов стало особенно много.

Comment: Подобным вопросам рады на Мете: https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 4):

Прежде всего нужно определиться, с какими целями создавался данный форум и какие перспективы обозначают создатели ресурса.

Отвечать на все вопросы подряд - это, с одной стороны, привлечение новых участников форума, даже бестолковых школяров, которые, возможно, благодаря форуму захотят больше узнать о русском языке. С другой стороны, когда форум превращается в сборник упражнений из учебника, тут становится неинтересно, и есть опасность, что уйдет часть пользователей, которые пришли сюда не за школьными заданиями.

Еще один важный вопрос - наполнение форума. Из учебника или нет, но новые вопросы должны появляться регулярно. Насколько эти вопросы должны быть глукобомысленными и сколько их будет достаточно - решать опять же создателям ресурса.

Так что всё на усмотрение администрации и модераторов.

Comment: Решать нельзя отказаться

Comment: Насколько я представляю, создатели ресурса против низкокачественного контента от нерадивых школьников и студентов. Но ту грань, насколько вы готовы отвечать на домашние задания, решает само сообщество: например, на Математике решили очень много задач предстоящего ЕГЭ, а на ХэшКоде учебные задания почти всегда сразу закрываются.

Answer (score 3):

Отвечать во время экзамена, олимпиады - противозаконно, во время подготовки - за 1-2-3 дня - почему нет? Пусть хоть перед экзаменом узнают, как правильно, лучше запомнится, а после экзамена - сам Бог велел, пусть успокоится, переживает ведь, правильно или неправильно ответил. Если целиком "требует" выполнить задание - не стоит, а если разобраться в трудностях - я "за". Так что к каждому вопросу стоит подходить индивидуально.

Comment: Просто, часто ведь видно, что самим им лень делать задания, и они думают, что тут за них сделают. А потом не могут ни слова без ошибок написать.

Comment: Такие случаи, конечно, тоже есть, нужно им говорить, что сайт создан не для этих целей, они привыкли к "Ответам", там есть форум "Домашние задания", но полностью выполнять задания там тоже отказываются, вот и ищут, кто сделает. Таких сразу видно, они готовы 10 заданий написать, их, конечно, следует закрывать. А если какие-то трудности в одном - можно и ответить. В колледже иногда довольно трудные задания. Почему бы не помочь?Самим интересно.

Answer (score 1):

[Вот](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/19591/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5), пример закрытого школьного вопроса. Если посмотреть, [предыдущий вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/19555/%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%8D-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8) спрашивающего, то можно увидеть, что домашние задания по русскому языку его уже вряд ли интересуют, так как ЕГЭ он уже написал, скорей всего, вопрос именно с ним и связан.
Если вдуматься, то установить, что появилось раньше курица или яйцо не так-то просто. Какой смысл у глагола "путешествовать" при отсутствии слова "путешествие"? Сказать " еду(иду) в..." намного быстрее и проще, чем "путешествую в...", в то время как для обозначения состояния нахождения в пути, других подходящих слов нет. Неслучайно почти все словари дают определение к "путешествовать", как "совершать путешествие". Да и то, что у Афанасия Никитина было "**хождение**",  а не путешествие, говорит о сравнительно позднем появлении этого слова и о том, что существительное могло быть неологизмом для обозначения литературного жанра, соответственно образоваться сращением 2-х основ.
Я тут не берусь, утверждать, что ответ @Ларf, неправильный (для ЕГЭ видимо он и требовался), но то, что вопрос не так прост и вряд ли заслуживал закрытия, отметить думаю стоит.

А по поводу, отвечать (закрывать) или нет... Вопросы плана, сделайте за меня домашнюю работу, можно было бы и закрывать часа на 24. После этого срока домашнее задание будет уже неактуальным, а вот кому интересно может и ответят.

На данный момент вопросов на проекте крайне мало, а если убрать задания с мульт-аккаунтов администрации, то и вообще почти нет. Формат для серьёзной научной дискуссии здесь не очень подходящий и почему бы тогда не привлекать сюда школьников, которые могут попасть сюда ища вопрос через поисковик. Ресурсы опытных членов форума, позволяют пресечь любой троллинг и оффтоп ещё в зародыше, а новые члены проекту не помешают.

Comment: Вы можете переоткрыть вопрос, если считаете, что он всё-таки заслуживает обсуждения.

Answer (score 1):

Я за то, чтобы нещадно уничтожать все скучные, неинтересные, *очевидные* (на взгляд модератора) вопросы (не обязательно из ЕГЭ). Сразу же готов был безапелляционно высказать здесь это мнение.

Но потом решил всё-таки проверить себя (и реакцию сообщества) и поставил небольшой опыт, задав вопрос о происхождении слова *тарелка*. Я бы, будучи модератором, сразу закрыл (и даже удалил бы) этот вопрос, так как не ожидал узнать ничего нового. Но получил ответы, которые меня удивили (для меня было очевидным то, что в ответах оспаривалось).

Видимо, существующая сейчас предельно "мягкая" модерация данного форума вполне отвечает интересам сообщества (ну, и целям ресурса). Слишком уж многосторонен сам предмет изучения, почти всегда позволяющий найти новые, неожиданные решения казалось бы давно уже решённых вопросов.

А "плохие", скучные вопросы получают молчаливое голосование "ногами" - участники их просто игнорируют, и этого, видимо, на данный момент вполне достаточно.

Answer (score 0):

По опыту общения со школьными вопросами в инете могу сказать, что вне экзамена, олимпиады и домашнего задания вопросов почти не задают. А если и задают, то честно говорят, что это домашнее задание - и проблема в такой-то его части.
Все остальное - на 99% желание найти готовые ответы на самостоятельную работу.
В общем-то тоже самое - и по другим предметам, но русский в этом смысле лидирует.
Возможно, специфика дисциплины, в которой ответ и решение суть одно и то же.
А возможно, просто отношение отвечающих такое... Ибо вряд ли кто на "взрослом" (в хорошем смысле) ресурсе будет решать элементарную задачку по математике за девятый класс, а с русским - не поленятся разжевать даже то, что ЖИ и ШИ пишется с буквой И, (а ЖЫ и ШЫ - с Ы).
Это не ворчание, это многолетние наблюдение.

Ко всему прочему есть еше тонкий момент, что отвечая на вопросы ЕГЭ, не будучи человеком из той среды, можно оказать поистине медвежью услугу. Во многие знания - многия печали. На ЕГЭ надо как автомат галочки ставить, а не рассуждать. А мы тут головы заморачиваем...

Для себя я нашел некий компромисс в том, что отвечаю на ЕГЭшные вопросы только тогда, когда они интересны сами по себе - и предупреждаю обычно, что моё мнение вполне может не совпасть с мнением авторов вопросов. Другими словами, отвечаю на вопрос так, как бы ответил вне связи с тем, где он задан - и какой ответ подразумевается автором.

В конце концов ни один ресурс не декларирует задачу помочь студенту или школьнику списать готовый ответ или помочь непосредственно на экзамене.